# UnicodeDecodeError when write to excel using python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I try to add_sheet to exccel file with

`df.groupby('member_id').apply(lambda x: add_xlsx_sheet(x, u'Десктопы полно'.decode('utf-8'), path='{}.xlsx'.format(x.name)))`

function

```
def add_xlsx_sheet(df, sheet_name=u'Смартфоны кратко', index=True, digits=2, path=None):
book = load_workbook(path)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path, engine='openpyxl')
writer.book = book
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)
if sheet_name in list(writer.sheets.keys()):
    sh = book.get_sheet_by_name(sheet_name)
    book.remove_sheet(sh)
df.to_excel(excel_writer=writer, sheet_name=sheet_name, startrow=0, startcol=0,
            float_format='%.{}f'.format(digits), index=index, encoding='utf-8')
writer.save()
```

and get error

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/�����/PycharmProjects/14-27/desktop.py", line 142, in <module>
    df.groupby('member_id').apply(lambda x: add_xlsx_sheet(x, u'Десктопы полно'.decode('utf-8'), path='{}.xlsx'.format(x.name)))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 651, in apply
    return self._python_apply_general(f)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 655, in _python_apply_general
    self.axis)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 1527, in apply
    res = f(group)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 647, in f
    return func(g, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/�����/PycharmProjects/14-27/desktop.py", line 142, in <lambda>
    df.groupby('member_id').apply(lambda x: add_xlsx_sheet(x, u'Десктопы полно'.decode('utf-8'), path='{}.xlsx'.format(x.name)))
  File "C:/Users/�����/PycharmProjects/14-27/desktop.py", line 137, in add_xlsx_sheet
    float_format='%.{}f'.format(digits), index=index)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1425, in to_excel
    startrow=startrow, startcol=startcol)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py", line 1257, in write_cells
    xcell.value = _conv_value(cell.val)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\cell\cell.py", line 291, in value
    self._bind_value(value)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\cell\cell.py", line 190, in _bind_value
    value = self.check_string(value)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\cell\cell.py", line 149, in check_string
    value = unicode(value, self.encoding)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xc4 in position 0: invalid continuation byte`

Why does it happen?
But when I try add_sheet without rewriting files

```
df1.groupby('member_id').apply(lambda x: add_xlsx_sheet(x, u'Десктопы кратко', path='{}.xlsx'.format(x.name)))
df.groupby('member_id').apply(lambda x: add_xlsx_sheet(x, u'Десктопы полно', path='{}.xlsx'.format(x.name)))
```

it returns error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/�����/PycharmProjects/14-27/desktop.py", line 141, in <module>
    df1.groupby('member_id').apply(lambda x: add_xlsx_sheet(x, u'Десктопы кратко', path='{}.xlsx'.format(x.name)))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 651, in apply
    return self._python_apply_general(f)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 655, in _python_apply_general
self.axis)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 1527, in apply
res = f(group)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 647, in f
    return func(g, *args, **kwargs)
   File "C:/Users/�����/PycharmProjects/14-27/desktop.py", line 141, in <lambda>
    df1.groupby('member_id').apply(lambda x: add_xlsx_sheet(x, u'Десктопы кратко', path='{}.xlsx'.format(x.name)))
  File "C:/Users/�����/PycharmProjects/14-27/desktop.py", line 138, in add_xlsx_sheet
    writer.save()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py", line 732, in save
return self.book.save(self.path)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py", line 294, in save
    save_workbook(self, filename)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 270, in save_workbook
    writer.save(filename)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 251, in save
self.write_data()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 94, in write_data
archive.writestr(ARC_WORKBOOK, write_workbook(self.workbook))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\workbook.py", line 85, in write_workbook
active = get_active_sheet(wb)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\workbook.py", line 59, in get_active_sheet
sheet = wb.active
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py", line 115, in active
return self._sheets[self._active_sheet_index]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: does it work if you remove `.decode('utf-8')`?

Comment: @MaxU, return this error too

Comment: can you post a full error traceback?

Comment: @MaxU add to question

Comment: try to add `encoding='utf-8'` parameter to the `to_excel()` call in the `add_xlsx_sheet()` function

Comment: @MaxU it's strange, but now it returns `KeyError: "There is no item named 'xl/_rels/workbook.xml.rels' in the archive"`

Comment: Congratulations! We've just fixed `UnicodeDecodeError` error. :)

Comment: I try to not overwrite files, but when I `df.groupby('member_id').apply(lambda y: add_xlsx_sheet(y, u'Десктопы полно', path='{}.xlsx'.format(y.name), encoding='utf-8'))` it return lsat error

Comment: but i suggested you to add `encoding='utf-8'` as a parameter of the `to_excel()` function, which should be called inside `add_xlsx_sheet()`

Comment: can you post the source code of the `add_xlsx_sheet()` function?

Comment: @MaxU add function

Comment: if you have another error now, could you rewrite your question and post a full error traceback for the current error?

Comment: @MaxU add to question

Comment: You are 100.00% SURE the encoding is utf-8?  The originally-posted error seems to indicate an encoding problem.

Comment: @SurestTexas this code works with other data

Answer (score 0):

The error is occuring due to the code snippet

```
u'Десктопы полно'.decode('utf-8')
```

The prefix 'u' makes a string a *Unicode string*. 
The Unicode string is not actually encoded in anyway and is already in the decoded form.

For example,

```
>>> s='Десктопы полно'
>>> u=u'Десктопы полно'
>>> s
'\xd0\x94\xd0\xb5\xd1\x81\xd0\xba\xd1\x82\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbf\xd1\x8b \xd0\xbf\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbb\xd0\xbd\xd0\xbe'
>>> u
u'\u0414\u0435\u0441\u043a\u0442\u043e\u043f\u044b \u043f\u043e\u043b\u043d\u043e'
>>> s.decode('utf-8')
u'\u0414\u0435\u0441\u043a\u0442\u043e\u043f\u044b \u043f\u043e\u043b\u043d\u043e'
>>> u.encode('utf-8')
'\xd0\x94\xd0\xb5\xd1\x81\xd0\xba\xd1\x82\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbf\xd1\x8b \xd0\xbf\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbb\xd0\xbd\xd0\xbe'
```

We can see that *s == u.encode('utf-8')*

For further detailed explanation as to why, you can go through http://pythoncentral.io/python-unicode-encode-decode-strings-python-2x/

So, basically, the Unicode string has to be encoded and not decoded, i.e. ,

```
u'Десктопы полно'.encode('utf-8')
```

Comment: Now it returns `ValueError: Worksheet titles must be unicode`